# How to prove that two sequence formulas are the same

Tags: sequences-and-series

I derived the formula for the nth term of a sequence to be $$\frac{1-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i}{2},$$ but upon inspection this appeared to be the same as $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n.$$ I was wondering how to prove that these are the same more rigorously?

Comment: What's $ a_1 $?

Comment: The nature of the bigger question suggests that the first term will be 1/2. Is this not necessarily true from the first nth formula?

Comment: @Bernard For $n=1$ the formula includes a sum with the upper limit less than the lower limit, this is usually interpreted as an empty sum with value $0$, so $a_1=1/2$

Comment: yeah my notation is definitely very dodgy. I meant that the nth term would be (1- the sum of the previous terms)/2. The first term being 1/2

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: You can use induction. For the inductive step, you'll need the formula
$$x+x^2+\dots+x^n=x(1+x+\dots+x^{n-1})=x\,\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$$
with $x=\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Proof without words:
[image: image representing a geometric sequence]
Image source: [Wikipedia's page about geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\left( \frac 12 \right)^n $ is a geometric sequence you may want to prove $a_n$ is one too. Indeed
$$
a_{n+1}=\frac{1-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}{2}=\frac{1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i}{2}-\frac{a_n}{2}=a_n-\frac{a_n}{2}=\frac{1}{2} a_n.
$$

Of course you need $a_1=\frac 12$.